# How to find words before/after certain keywords?

Tags: python, regex

I am using the following code to count the number of phrases in a doc file:

```
phrases = ['yellow bananas']
clean_text = " ".join(re.findall(r'\w+(?:-\w+)*', doc))
for phrase in phrases:
    if phrase in clean_text:
        if phrase not in list_of_phrases:
            list_of_phrases[phrase] = clean_text.count(phrase)
        else:
            list_of_phrases[phrase] += clean_text.count(phrase)
```

The question is, is it possible instead of getting the whole sentence, to get one, two, three etc words before/after the keywords I am searching for?

EDIT:

Sample doc:

```
Yellow bananas are nice. I like fruits. Nobody knows how many fruits there are out there. There are yellow bananas and many other fruits. Bananas, apples, oranges, mangos.
```

Ouput would be a count of phrases that contain the keyword e.g. 'yellow bananas' in this case with 1,2,3 etc. words before and after the keywords.

Comment: Please show us the expected output you want.

Comment: Please also give a sample for doc; your expression makes it look like hyphenated words.

Comment: Hello. I edited my original post.